# OpenCV installed, undefined references to 3rdParty stuff while building program

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install **OpenCV 4.6** on my Ubuntu 22.4 Laptop (NVIDIA RTX 3070)

I'm following this tutorial:
https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Compiling_OpenCV_from_Source
(I tried theirs git, but the original one as well)

I installed

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake pkg-config unzip yasm git checkinstall
sudo apt install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libwebp-dev libdc1394-dev
sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libavresample-dev
sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
sudo apt install libxvidcore-dev x264 libx264-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libtheora-dev
sudo apt install libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libvorbis-dev
sudo apt install libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libopenexr-dev

sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libxine2-dev libv4l-dev v4l-utils
sudo ln -s -f /usr/include/libv4l1-videodev.h /usr/include/linux/videodev.h

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev

sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install -U pip numpy
sudo apt install python3-testresources

sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get install libgoogle-glog-dev libgflags-dev
sudo apt-get install libgphoto2-dev libeigen3-dev libhdf5-dev
```

And changed flags to

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \                                                                      *[develop]
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
–D WITH_VTK=OFF \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=${GPU_ARCH} \
-D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_IPP=OFF \
-D WITH_EIGEN=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python2) \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

I confirmed my CUDA and CUDNN installation - examples from both are building and running.

Installation `make -> make install` is not throwing any errors and all is proceeding correctly (from what can I say)

Build info:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0-dev =====================================
  Version control:               2a4926f

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/v/Install/OpenCVRidge/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     940d910

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-01-31T12:21:32Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.22.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (18 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (33 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (8 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 11.3.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so Iconv::Iconv m pthread cudart_static dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libopenjp2 quirc

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cvv java julia matlab ovis python2 sfm viz
    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  GUI:                           GTK3
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.33)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.72.4)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
    WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.3.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf-2_5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread-2_5.so (ver 2_5)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.6)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.20.3)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2021.5 interface 12050)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.8, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.7.0)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/v/Install/OpenCVRidge/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.10.6)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so (ver 3.10.6)
    numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.24.1)
    install path:                /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.10

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

so all what I wanted is ok - **CUDA, CUDNN, Gstreamer**
My python also is seeing opencv - `import cv2`

Here's the problem tho, when I try to compile my cpp program - some video capture and Net detection (but it doesn't seem to be related), I get a wall of  **undefined referances** to some third party code:
ex:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG4openEPKcidiiRKN2cv21VideoWriterParametersE+0x663): undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context'
/usr/bin/ld: cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG4openEPKcidiiRKN2cv21VideoWriterParametersE+0x6a0): undefined reference to `av_malloc'
/usr/bin/ld: cap_ffmpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG4openEPKcidiiRKN2cv21VideoWriterParametersE+0x71f): undefined reference to `av_log_set_level'
```

or

```
(.text._ZNK17opencv_tensorflow19AttrValue_ListValue18_InternalSerializeEPhPN6google8protobuf2io19EpsCopyOutputStreamE+0x3d4): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::EnsureSpaceFallback(unsigned char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: attr_value.pb.cc:(.text._ZNK17opencv_tensorflow19AttrValue_ListValue18_InternalSerializeEPhPN6google8protobuf2io19EpsCopyOutputStreamE+0x3e4): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::EnsureSpaceFallback(unsigned char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: attr_value.pb.cc:(.text._ZNK17opencv_tensorflow19AttrValue_ListValue18_InternalSerializeEPhPN6google8protobuf2io19EpsCopyOutputStreamE+0x3f7): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::EnsureSpaceFallback(unsigned char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: attr_value.pb.cc
```

Which I don't use and should not need to link in any way - as that should be part of basic OpenCV installation.

I compile with this makefile (maybe that's the problem?)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(vision)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set_target_properties(${TARGETS} PROPERTIES CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion)
endif()

link_directories(
  /usr/local/lib
  /usr/local/cuda/lib64
  /usr/local/lib/opencv4/3rdparty
  )

link_libraries(
  -latomic
  -lrt
  -lpthread
  -lstdc++fs
  -lcuda
  -lcudart
  -lopencv_core
  -lopencv_tracking
  -lopencv_videoio
  -lopencv_imgproc
  -lopencv_highgui
  -lopencv_ml
  -lopencv_video
  -lopencv_features2d
  -lopencv_calib3d
  -lopencv_objdetect
  -lopencv_flann
  -lopencv_dnn
  -lopencv_imgcodecs
  -lstdc++fs
  -lopencv_cudawarping
  -lopencv_cudev
  -lopencv_cudacodec
  )

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(my_api REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  src/core/
  /usr/local/include/opencv4
  /usr/include/opencv4
)

# include_directories(${HEADER})

file(GLOB SOURCES
  src/*.cpp
  src/core/*.cpp
)

add_executable(vision ${SOURCES})
ament_target_dependencies(vision rclcpp std_msgs my_api)

install(TARGETS
  vision
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()
```

But when I try to compile I get this - [txt file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a3f9900424d3aac0243afd6dc129ad8d20230131140001/d855a4)

Thank you for your time, any help is appreciated.

I expacted to compile without problems at all, I used that installation method on different devices and it worked fine. That program is also compilable without errors on different device with opencv - thats why I'm expecting the problem to be OpenCV installation or/and incorrect Makefile?

That's not a solution and duplicate of: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)
The program is working on different machine and installation proceeded the same way so the paths should be correct if someone feels that I incorrectly link opencv in Makefile please tell me how to do that's how it's working on a different machine, and how people on the internet do that.

Comment: you need to link to the ffmpeg and protobuf libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles why should I? Even if that help - it's not a correct solution.
They are part of OpenCV installation, I never needed to do that. Also that two are only a small part of all errors (please check the attached file)

Comment: If you don't want to link to those libraries then make sure they're not enabled when building opencv

Comment: @AlanBirtles So for an unknown reason it's not working on my laptop - while working everywhere else without linking them specifically? Is opencv not using them somewhere inside itself? Will disabling nearly everything not impact basic performance (cv::__ methods) in any way? Besides, I need to use Gstreamer and it also appears in the undefined references list :(
If because of some bug there's a need to link everything specifically, are there any examples of that? List of -l needed? Don't tell me that I need to look thru that file and check each and every lib that appears there.

Comment: opencv should have generated a cmake configuration file allowing you to use `find_package`, you shouldn't need to manually link to anything https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html

Comment: Exactly my point. pkg-config is only linking -lopencv_* libs( no additional ones, no "protobuf" "ffmpeg" etc) and 3rdparty which I even added myself "/usr/local/lib/opencv4/3rdparty", just to be sure. Why it's not working for me?